# Why is my ScrollView code not displaying?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have copied some files across from one project to another. The code simply displays a view you can scroll horizontally between items, and then scroll down each item.

The code was in a project with a MainWindow.xib and the relevant name in the plist file.

I'm putting the code into an empty OpenGL ES project which has no nib information in the plist file, and two nib files called "ProjectNameViewController_iPhone.xib" and "ProjectNameViewController_iPad.xib"

When I run the program, none of my code displays. I have a feeling the problem lies with where I am adding subviews to the view controller, and calling this line:

```
- (id)initWithPageNumber:(int)page
{
    if (self = [super initWithNibName:@"MyView" bundle:nil])
    {
        pageNumber = page;
        [self.view addSubview:newsItem];
    }
    return self;
}
```

First of all, It's odd to me that the string here is "MyView" and not "MainWindow" as there is nothing in my project called "MyView" (I've searched the project directory and the code is being called)

but getting back to the point, the new code in the open GL ES project is this:

```
- (id)initWithPageNumber:(int)page
{
    if (self = [super initWithNibName:@"IntegrationTestViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil])
    {
        pageNumber = page;
        [self.view addSubview:newsItem];
    }
    return self;
}
```

I will put in a check later for Ipad users etc.. If the string is anything else, the code breaks when other parts try to access the classes view which doesn't exist, but with this nothing displays.

what am I not understanding? (I'm quite new to ios / objective-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the outlets mad to ProjectNameViewController_iPhone.xib and File's owner class.

Comment: can you elaborate on what those are and how to 'check' them? thank you.

Comment: In interface Builder, open ProjectNameViewController_iPhone.xib and open connection inspector from tools menu and check out outlets that you made in your code are properly connected or not.

Comment: and what would be there if they were properly connected? it appears as if there is a connection from view to file's owner under referencing outlets. In file's owner under outlets it says 'view - View'

Comment: what is newsitem and remember you are initializing from nib and adding subView which will not show any thing because view pointer of viewController is not initialized yet. It initializes in the viewDidLoad . I would like to see your view hierarchy